# stopwatch, updating log windows form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I have a stopwatch, and would like to update the log of the times you started and stopped the watch

something like this:
[image]

As you can see at beginning it's empty, first use it and a row with use number and duration, and you use more times more lines show up. I have look up for ways to do it but i find none, i thouth of creating a tablelayoutpanel but i can't put data in them.

Any ideias of how to do this?

Thanks,

Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry i forgot to mention i'm using VB, i tried aplying your code but couldnt get i to work, but a found a solution

i used a listview controller, and configured it for the 4 columns i need, then when the stop button is clicked i put the code:

```
newitem = New ListViewItem
newitem.Text = pausa
newitem.SubItems.Add(inicio.ToLongTimeString)
newitem.SubItems.Add(fim.ToLongTimeString)
newitem.SubItems.Add(diferença.ToString.Substring(0, 8))
ListView1.Items.Add(newitem)
```

and it's working fine.

Hope it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx), with a custom `UserControl` for your number and duration, you will need the `UserControl` because if you tell the Panel stack vertically you will not be able to add adjacent items. You also did not mention which language you are programming in so I will give you and example in C#: See if this gives you an idea.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel() 
                                  { Width = 200, 
                                    Height = 200, 
                                    AutoScroll = true, 
                                    FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown ,
                                    Location = new Point(0,0),
                                    WrapContents = false 
                                  };
        Button btn = new Button() { Text = "Add", 
                                    Height = 30, 
                                    Width = 70, 
                                    Location = new Point(200, 200) 
                                  };
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Controls.Add(flp);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flp.Controls.Add(new myUserControl() { Number = "1", 
                                                   Duration = "00:00:00"
                                                 });
        }
    }

    public class myUserControl:UserControl
    {
        Label number = new Label(){ ForeColor = Color.Blue,
                                    Font = new Font("Arial", 14),
                                    AutoSize = true,
                                    Location = new Point(0,0)
                                  };

        Label duration = new Label(){ ForeColor = Color.Red,
                                      Font = new Font("Arial", 14),
                                      AutoSize = true,
                                      Location = new Point(24, 0)
                                    };

        public  myUserControl()
        {
            this.Size = new Size(new Point(150, 24));
            this.Controls.Add(number);
            this.Controls.Add(duration);
        }

        public string Number
        {
            get { return number.Text; }
            set { number.Text = value; }
        }

        public string Duration
        {
            get { return duration.Text; }
            set { duration.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```